# Treating a 1D data structure as 2D grid

Tags: data-structures, math, graphics

I am working with a native class that represents a 2D image as a 1D array. If you want to change one pixel, for example, you need to now how to derive the index from the `x,y` coordinates.

So, let's say we have a 1D array `array1d` like this:

```
array1d = [ a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y ]
```

In the context of our program, `array1d` represents a 2D grid:

```
a b c d e
f g h i j
k l m n o
p q r s t
u v w x y
```

And we want to perform operations on `array1d` such as:

- Get the value at `x,y` coordinates (in this example, `1,2` would give `l`)
- Get any sub-grid using `x,y,width,height` (`1,2,2,2` would give `[l, m, q, r]`)
- Set the value at any `x,y` coordinate (etc.)

How do we do these?

Comment: In Matlab, and thus likely math types (which spills into CS), to convert one matrix into another (be it a 1x12 into a 2x6 or a 2x6 into a 3x4) is known as "reshaping" http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html

Comment: @MichaelT: the OP is not reshaping the grid. No mention of reshaping the  5x5 to anything else (which wouldn't make sense anyway). :)

Comment: @IAbstract that question *was* in [revision 1](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/212808/revisions) though.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

2D / 1D - mapping is pretty simple. Given x and y, and 2D array sizes `width` (for x-direction) and `height` (for y-direction), you can calculate the according index `i` in 1D space (zero-based) by

```
i = x + width*y;
```

and the reverse operation is

```
x = i % width;    // % is the "modulo operator", the remainder of i / width;
y = i / width;    // where "/" is an integer division
```

You can extend this easily to 3 or more dimensions. For example, for a 3D matrix with dimensions "width", "height" and "depth":

```
i = x + width*y + width*height*z;
```

and reverse:

```
x = i % width;
y = (i / width)%height;
z = i / (width*height);
```

Comment: @awashburn that is the traditional way to do it, it's even built into compilers for static 2D arrays

Comment: @mtoast: I don't think so, its just basic integer math.

Comment: This example is wrong for 3D. The word depth in the calculation should be height.

Comment: @jiggunjer: thanks for the correction, changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: No problem, you might also want to mention the example is for row major indexing.

Comment: Great!!! Saved me a few hours of head-scratching because you have the 1D -> 3D conversion. Great job! Would you mind me adding a practical implementation? I'm using a byte[] from a BinaryStream. I can give one for both 3D -> 1D and (now) 1D -> 3D.

Comment: @IAbstract: you do not need to ask me for this if you want to write an own answer. But be sure you understand how the Programmers site works, if an answer will not add any real additional value and mostly repeats what another guy already wrote, some people might downvote the answer.

Comment: @DocBrown: I don't think my answer would provide any additional value. My implementation uses your answer. Sometimes people seeking answers are inspired by practical snippets where an answer has been put into use.

Comment: What is we don't want to have it 0-indexed

Comment: @makakas: that is an exercise left to the reader ;-). Hint: you have to add/substract the lower bound as an offset at the right places. But before you try this, clarify to yourself which of the two arrays you mean, the 1D or the 2D array.

Comment: @DocBrown Sorry my comment is terribly written, but I was trying to figure out the reverse function for 1-indexed arrays and this is what I found, for anyone looking for it in the future   int x = (num-1)%width+1;   
  int y = (num-1)/(width)+1;

Comment: How might this be done for a system which also includes negative values of x,y when you need to make sure they all map to indices > -1 for computer arrays.

Comment: @WDUK: you need to know the minimal values for x and y. Lets say you have xmin<0 and ymin<0. Now you replace "x" by "x-xmin" and "y" by "y-ymin" in the first formula above (for calculating i). For the reverse operation, you do the opposite and replace x by "x+xmin" and "y" by "y+min".